# Retrieving Distance to Top of a Dynamically Added Element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In my case, I'm adding buttons dynamically. Each button that is added has a different class. I have style rules set up so that each subsequent button will be placed below the previous button. So, what I need is to find the distance to top to each button in order to use it later for logic.

I tried two ways to retrieve the distance to top in the code below. the first using native javascript, which I stored as: `var = h`. The second time around I tried more of a D3 approach, which I stored as: `var = h2`.

```
d3.select('body').append('button')
    .text('X')
    .attr('id','button'+(intCount+1))
    .attr('class',choice+'1')
    .on('click', function(d,i) {
    var t = d3.select(this).attr('id')
    var c = d3.select(this).attr('class')
    var h = document.getElementByID(t).offsetTop;
    var h2 = d3.select(this).offsetTop
      var thisChoice = choice;

      d3.selectAll('.' + t).remove();
      d3.selectAll('.'+ thisChoice+'1').remove();
      intCount -= 1;
      count -= .7;
    });
```

Both of these return null in the console log. Oh actually, one gave me an error, and the other returned undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your *D3 approach* you only need `this`, not `d3.select(this)`, which will return a D3 selection:

```js
d3.select('body').append('button')
  .text('X')
  .on('click', function() {
    var h2 = this.offsetTop;
    console.log(h2)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Regarding your *native JS approach*, you have a typo: it is `getElementById`, not `getElementByID`:

```js
d3.select('body').append('button')
  .text('X')
  .attr("id", "foo")
  .on('click', function() {
    var t = d3.select(this).attr("id");
    var h = document.getElementById(t).offsetTop;
    console.log(h)
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: PS: I'm only answering your question here, nothing more. However, I have a strong feeling that this is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: That's right, I will use the top distance to try to modify different element's y position through `translate` or other means. If I can't figure it out from here I will post a new question. Thanks for your explanation!